# Unable to delete file with complete path in c++

Tags: c++, file

I am using `visual studio 2017` and working in c++. I have code where I take some input from the user and based on that I am trying to delete a file.

```
auto ver = FLAGS_ver;  // taking input from the user

string file = "C:\\Program Files(x86)\\data_" + ver + "\\output\\output.json";

std::ofstream output_file(outputFile);
```

Basically `ver` is a number based on which that particular directory is accessed. So final `string file` becomes:

```
C:\\Program Files(x86)\\data_209\\output\\output.json
```

So I need to delete above file for which I am using below command:

```
int res = remove(file);
```

But it shows below error:

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::remove" matches the argument list

Error   C2664   'int remove(const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'const char *'
```

I am able to write to this json file so there is no issues with permission. How can I resolve this. Thanks

Comment: `remove(file.c_str());`

Comment: According to error, `remove()` expects a C string (`const char*`) but you provide a `std::string`. You have to convert `std::string file` to C string using `file.c_str()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is `std::remove` expects a C-string (`const char *`). You can use the `c_str()` method from `std::string`.

```
int res = remove(file.c_str());
```

However, you could use the more appropriate C++ [std::filesystem::remove](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) (from C++17s [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)) to do the same. Now, Since you use Visual Studio 2017, `std::filesystem` was not [yet fully implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/filesystem?view=vs-2017), and you have to use the experimental version. To accomplish the same:

```
#include <filesystem>
// ...
std::experimental::filesystem::remove(file);
```